# Excluding projects from build in YAML configuration azure-pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to exclude some projects from building in *azure pipelines*.

I tried the following options...

- Trying to build only the projects under core?

```
- script: dotnet build **/Core/*.csproj --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
```

and

```
- script: dotnet build **/Core/**/*.csproj --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
```

- Trying to use the task @DotnNetCli2.0
- Referenced the [yaml file matching patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops#question_mark_examples)

But couldn't find a good example.

The projects I want to build are under different subfolders as in `../../Core/Domain/Domain.csproj` *and* `../../Core/Presentation/Presentation.csproj`

Is there something I'm missing, is it possible; or am I just plain doing something wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just use the dotnetcore cli task with something like this:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
  command: 'build'
  projects: |
      '**/*.csproj'
      '!**/*Mobile*.csproj' # This ignores projects with the occurrence of Mobile anywhere in the filename
```