# How to specify a path with exclusions in yaml

Tags: yaml, glob, matching, string-matching

I'm relatively new to yaml and have some azure pipelines to maintain.

The variable below is used to run unit tests in azure DevOps but there has now been added a test project named `Api.Tests.RestSharp` which I wish to be excluded from being run

```
unitTestsGlob: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\**\*Tests\*.csproj
```

How can I update this to exclude a specific project name?

Comment: In YAML there is no such thing as a path. For YAML you have a  single key and value in a root level block style mapping, nothing special about that.

Comment: I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60321752/excluding-projects-from-build-in-yaml-configuration-azure-pipelines

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
unitTestsGlob: |
    $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\**\*Tests\*.csproj
    !$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\**\*RestSharp*\*.csproj
```